# Why does D mark this function as pure nothrow @nogc?

Tags: d

```d
alias PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT = 
  VkBool32 function(VkDebugReportFlagsEXT flags,
                    VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objectType,
                    uint64_t object, size_t location, 
                    int32_t messageCode, const char* pLayerPrefix,
                    const char* pMessage, void* pUserData);

struct VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT {
    VkStructureType               sType = VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    const(void)*                  pNext;
    VkDebugReportFlagsEXT         flags;
    PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT  pfnCallback;
    void*                         pUserData;
}
```

..

```d
VkBool32 MyDebugReportCallback(
    VkDebugReportFlagsEXT       flags,
    VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT  objectType,
    uint64_t                    object,
    size_t                      location,
    int32_t                     messageCode,
    const char*                 pLayerPrefix,
    const char*                 pMessage,
    void*                       pUserData)
{
    return VK_FALSE;
}
auto debugcallbackCreateInfo = VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT(
    VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT,
    null,
    VkDebugReportFlagBitsEXT.VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT,
    &MyDebugReportCallback,
    null
);
```

> Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (& MyDebugReportCallback)
>   of type uint function(uint flags, VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT
>   objectType, ulong object, ulong location, int messageCode,
>   const(char*) pLayerPrefix, const(char*) pMessage, void* pUserData) to
>   uint function(uint flags, VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objectType, ulong
>   object, ulong location, int messageCode, const(char*) pLayerPrefix,
>   const(char*) pMessage, void* pUserData) pure nothrow @nogc

I don't understand why `PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT` is pure nothrow and @nogc? I just want to call `writeln` from within `MyDebugReportCallback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was quite obvious. It is inside a pure, nothrow and @nogc block

https://github.com/ParticlePeter/ErupteD/blob/master/source/erupted/types.d#L12

Comment: But why is it there? I think it was user error... the callback likely doesn't *need* to be those things and the author just didn't put the definition in the right place.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Yes I already opened an issue, https://github.com/ParticlePeter/ErupteD/issues/2